# set a variable equal to another variable plus one and save to user default in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a high score variable that saves and is equal to the score plus one when the score is greater or equal to the high score. I need this data to be pulled up everytime the game starts from NSUserDefaults and I would like to do it all in the view.

I am used to other languages and I have this code to start:

```
func newHighscore(_ duck: DuckView){
    if score >= highscore{
    return highscore = score + 1
 }

    lblHighscore.text = "HIGHSCORE: \(highscore)"
}
```

The high score let alone any score is not being printed in the label and I can't figure out why.

Please forgive my beginner mistakes.

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way but given that you have 3 fundamental errors on just one line of code, may I suggest that you spend some quality Time reading the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/index.html) book before going any further. Learning the basics will make your coding efforts go much better.

Comment: I used to write swift but it has been a while. I quickly jotted that down and it works in another language and I thought it would help to have a basis rather than blindly asking for help having put no work in. I will leave the question up and work on the code but I do have to refresh my memory. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Review what the assignment operator is versus the comparison operator. Review the addition operator versus the obsolete (in Swift) increment operator. Review variable scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if I understand this right, you want to make a method in which you can save a high score (score + 1) to User Defaults if the high score is less than or equal to the score.

First off, in Swift, to add one to a variable (assuming that variable is a numeric type) you just do `variable + 1`. Simple as that.

Now it looks like the rest of the code is fine enough for this circumstance. (Other than the duplicate high score variables) On to User Defaults.

In case you don't remember or really understand what **User Defaults** are, here's a quick beginner recap. **User Defaults** is a place where you can store basic data types (String, Int, Array, etc.) that is dedicated to your app and local to your device. This means that you can save a value in **User Defaults**, kill the app, come back in, and the data will still be stored in **User Defaults** under a certain key. A **User Defaults** key is a short string identifying where the data is stored. Say you create an array, and store it under the key "myArray". If you go to access it again any other time, you would look for the array under the key "myArray".

Applying **User Defaults** to your code is really simple.

First, you need to create a User Defaults standard object.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
```

This creates an object of User Defaults that you can save and access data from.

Next, you actually save the data under a key of, let's say `highScore`.

```
defaults.set(highscore, forKey: "highScore")
```

And that's it for saving your high core.
To access it, just use this code:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if defaults.integer(forKey: "highScore") != 0 {
        let newHighScore = defaults.integer(forKey: "highScore")
        //There is a value stored, and it is now in the varible newHighScore
        lblHighscore.text = "Pigs: \(newHighScore)"
    } else {
        //There is no high score stored yet
    }
```

What we are doing here is creating an instance of `UserDefaults` (defaults), checking to see if there is an integer stored for the key "highScore" (if there isn't, User Defaults will give you 0), and setting it to a variable that you can then use to do whatever you want.

I hope this helped you.

Just a side note though, I see you have a parameter called duck in your function of type `DuckView`. If you don't plan to use this in the function, I would suggest removing it to cleanse your code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

So, I’m not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here’s what I believe you are looking for:

```
let score = 10
var highscore = 10

if score >= highscore {
    highscore = score + 1
}
print(highscore)
```

As you can see, there are a few issues with this line:

```
let highscore == score++1
```

If the variable you are trying to increment, `highscore`, is a global variable, you can’t say “let highscore...” using the same name.

Also, `==` is just for comparison, you can’t compare and assign at the same time.

There’s also the `++1` thing in the end, there is no `++` in Swift anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help correcting my code. I still need a way to save it. I think I should use NSUserDefaults but I can't get the high score to load back after the app is closed.

Comment: what do I set my variable equal to?

Comment: @SamsonT if I understood your question correctly, you should declare `highscore` as a variable somewhere outside that function, if you need to access it throughout the whole class, and just do `highscore = score + 1` to have it be 1 point higher than what the `score` variable has in it.

Comment: @SamsonT As for saving it, if you are doing this just as an exercise to learn iOS development, then it's ok to use `UserDefaults` which is the Swift version of `NSUserDefaults`. But if you are actually making an app, then you'll have to look into real persistence, database, options.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean to 'duck'?

> duck: DuckView
>   I think you should declare properly the variable first and then the method/function.

You can use this as your reference.

```
func getHighscore(score: Int, highscore:Int) -> Int{

     if score >= highscore{
        return highscore = score + 1
     }else{
       // add your formula here
       return highscore
     }        
}
```

you can call this method using self.getHighscore(score: 3, highscore: 2)

```
self.lblHighscore.text = "Pigs: \(self.getHighscore(score: 3, highscore: 2))" //This will return a new highscore value which is 4
```

Comment: A duck is an object you are trying to get. They are flying ducks that have later been switched to pigs that you are trying to shoot.